# Market Cap Data in R in Yahoo vs Google

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

I am able to download market cap data from Yahoo using the QuantMod package in R.

`getQuote("MSFT", what = yahooQF(c("Market Capitalization")))`

While that works well for some stocks, the Market Cap seems off for others.

For example, consider this same stock via google and yahoo:

https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRYP.CN/

https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02ejSxpftcthUaHlBfHSVFfXQ0Tvw%3A1614362449675&ei=UTc5YJ3GKKW5ggfC6ZDABQ&q=TRYP%3ACNX+stock&oq=TRYP%3ACNX+stock&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQlRVYshZghxhoAnACeACAAWCIAf4BkgEBM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjdsufikIjvAhWlnOAKHcI0BFgQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Yahoo shows NA while google shows $51MM. Is there a compatible function in R where I can get the google market cap data?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly quantmod can no longer access google's market information as per this [issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/221). As an alternative somebody point to this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49466286/3056882) that could help you.